# How do I "describe the region" of $\Bbb R^3$ represented by an inequality?

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

I don't really understand what these two questions are asking. Nor do I know how to start it.

> 1) Describe in words the region of $\mathbb {R}^3$ represented by: $x^2 + z^2 \le  9$.
>
> 2) Write an inequality to describe: The solid upper hemisphere of the sphere of radius 2 centered at the origin.

Can some please explain what I am supposed to do here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $1$, the region of space satisfying that inequality will look like a familiar shape. Can you figure out what shape?

Comment: Depends on which way is up. They probably mean that up is $z\ge 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question no. $1$, notice that if we [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2Bz%5E2+%E2%89%A4+9) $x^2+z^2 \le 9$ in $\mathbb R^2$, we get a filled circle of radius $3$.  Add another axis, and what happens?  For example, a plate is a circle, but what 3d shape is made when plates are stacked?

For question no. $2$, recall that an (empty, i.e. not solid) [sphere](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2by%5E2%2bz%5E2=9%5E2) of radius $r$ has the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$.  Noting that the radius is $3$, we have $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$.  How do we now make this sphere filled?  Look at what was done in question $1$ to make a filled circle.

Comment: I'm sorry. Could you explain this a little more. I'm still kind of lost with this problem.

Comment: @Avalon-96 Edited.  Is it still unclear?

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes more sense. Thank you.